# down casting polimorphic objects

Tags: java, oop, casting

There is a data block containing continuous packed data of structures of different types. It is necessary to read this data into an array.
It was programmed like this:

```
class Handler{
    //...
    public List<MyStruct> getMyStructs(){
        // when processing, some subsequent data depends on the 
        // processing of the previous ones
    }

    //...
}

abstract class MyStruct{ 
    // Common method implementations for all structs 
}

class ImpulsOne extends MyStruct{
    // declaring and init fields 
    // methods
}

class ImpulsTwo extends MyStruct{
    // declaring and init fields
    // methods
}

//and etc...
```

After we have received the List, we live and enjoy life using the common methods that are in MyStruct.But this happens as long as there is no task to pull out and display or process several fields from several structures of certain types. There can be many such processing, and, unfortunately, each depends on the results of the previous processing.

The only thing I came up with is to do a downcast with each processing:

```
//...
    SomeResult processing1(List<MyStruct> structs){
        //...
        for(var struct: structs){
           if(struct instanceof ImpulsOne){
                ImpulsOne impuls = (ImpulsOne) struct
                // extracting fields and processing
           }else if(struct instanceof ImpulsTwo){
                ImpulsTwo = (ImpulsTwo) struct
                // extracting fields and processing
           }

           // and many many else-if
        }
    }
//...
```

I don't like this approach and I'm sure it can be made easier.

I hope I have clearly explained the whole essence of the problem. Have you faced a similar problem? What ideas do you have to simplify the code?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're in need of different behavior for each of your child classes, define an `abstract` method in `MyStruct` (for example a generic `executeAction` or so), then override that method in each child class. Then, all you need to do is `structs.forEach(MyStruct::executeAction);` or something similar, depending on what you need to return

Comment: If you are using recent jdk 17, you could switch instead of if-else. But @Qbrute 's approach is the better one.

Comment: @QBrute, thank you very much for your answer.  This solution is suitable if all structures have a common behavior that should be applied for each (for example, the draw() method for shapes).  But imagine, for example, that you have an array of shapes, and among the whole huge array of shapes, you need to display ONLY the radius of the circle and ONLY the diagonal of the square and nothing more. My situation is similar.

Comment: Search for the “Visitor Pattern”

Comment: @Holger is it possible to implement using strategy pattern?

Comment: @S.Sachith A Visitor is a kind of Strategy, so there’s no contradiction with it. But the Visitor Pattern is the one which tells you how you can provide different implementations for the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can shift from structures to objects. I mean you may put logic of processing into objects, do not extracting fields and processing its out of objects.

Currently you offer the following:

```
SomeResult processing1(List<MyStruct> structs) {
   for(var struct: structs){
      if(struct instanceof ImpulsOne){
         ImpulsOne impuls = (ImpulsOne) struct
         // extracting fields and processing
      } else if(struct instanceof ImpulsTwo){
         ImpulsTwo = (ImpulsTwo) struct
         // extracting fields and processing
      }
      // and many many else-if
      }
}
```

I suggest the following:

```
SomeResult processing1(List<MyStruct> structs) {
   for(var struct: structs){
      struct.process();
   }
}
```

And define a specific `process()` method for `ImpulsOne`, `ImpulsTwo`, etc.